# Print new line in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, printing

I am beginner at assembly language and I don't understand why the code#1 works and code#2 doesn't... Does anybody know how to help me?

I want to print a new line, so i have copied this code#1:

```
section .data
newline_char: db 10

section .text
global _start

print_newline:
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, newline_char
mov rdx, 1
syscall
```

But if i try the code#2, it doesn't work and the newline is not printed:

```
    ; I have removed the newline_char from here

    section .text
    global _start

    print_newline:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, 10 ; I tried to put immediatly in here and have already tested '0x0a' '0ah'
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `rsi` should not contain the character to print but rather the address of a buffer to print.  The first example sets `rsi` up correctly, the second one does not.  That's why it doesn't work as expected.  Also, thanks for writing a clear question!

Comment: So, can I make a 'push 0x10' and 'mov rsi, rsp' ?

Comment: That can be done of course.

Comment: The C equivalent of this is `write(1, (char*)10, 1)` which passes `10` (`'\n'`) as a pointer value.  If you passed that to `puts` or `printf` instead it would segfault, but system calls return `-EFAULT` on bad pointers.  Look at the return value with `strace ./my_program`